# Problem using the nextLine() and hasNextLine() methods of Scanner

Tags: java, java.util.scanner

I have a log file containing the following data:

Shortest path(2)::RV3280-RV0973C-RV2888C
Shortest path(1)::RV3280-RV2502C
Shortest path(2)::RV3280-RV2501C-RV1263
Shortest path(2)::RV2363-Rv3285-RV3280

From each line, i require the number within the brackets, name of the first protein (RV3280 in the first line) and the name of the last protein (RV2888C in the first line).

I have written a code for this using the `Scanner` object.

```
try{
                Scanner s = new Scanner(new File(args[0]));
                while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                    s.findInLine("Shortest path\\((\\d+)\\)::(\\w+).*-(\\w+)"); // at each line, look for this pattern
                    MatchResult result = s.match(); // results from
                    for (int i=1; i<=result.groupCount(); i++) {
                        System.out.println(result.group(i));
                    }
                    s.nextLine(); // line no. 29
                }
                s.close();
        }

        catch (FileNotFoundException e) {
            System.out.print("cannot find file");
        }
```

I get the desired results but i also get an error message. The output i get for the above input file is:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
        at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
        at nearnessindex.Main.main(Main.java:29)
2
RV3280
RV2888C
1
RV3280
RV2502C
2
RV3280
RV1263
2
RV2363
RV3280
Java Result: 1
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 1 second)
```

Why does this error occur and how can correct it?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Your input data probably doesn't end with a line separator which would cause this. Calls to `findInLine` moves the Scanner past the matching pattern and if you are at the end of the input data when calling `nextLine` it will throw the `NoSuchElementException`

A easy fix without re-arranging the code to much would be to end the while loop with:

```
if (s.hasNextLine()) {
    s.nextLine();
}
```

Comment: Hi Key, yes it works as soon as added a line separator. I didn't think about the moving of Scanner to the end of the line :) Thank you so much and thanks for the fix too.

Answer (score 0):

```
    public static void main(String[] args) {
            Scanner s = new Scanner("Shortest path(2)::RV3280-RV0973C-RV2888C"
                    + "\nShortest path(1)::RV3280-RV2502C"
                    + "\nShortest path(2)::RV3280-RV2501C-RV1263"
                    + "\nShortest path(2)::RV2363-Rv3285-RV3280");
            while (s.hasNextLine()) {
                s.findInLine("Shortest path\\((\\d+)\\)::(\\w+).*-(\\w+)"); // at each line, look for this pattern
                MatchResult result = s.match(); // results from
                for (int i = 1; i <= result.groupCount(); i++) {
                    System.out.println(result.group(i));
                }
                s.nextLine(); // line no. 29
            }
            s.close();
    }
}

run:
2
RV3280
RV2888C
1
RV3280
RV2502C
2
RV3280
RV1263
2
RV2363
RV3280
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

This works well for me, maybe you have some weird characters or empty lines in your file?

2 empty lines at the end give me that:
    Exception in thread "main" java.lang.IllegalStateException: No match result available

If your input file is that strictly formatted, you can do something like that, which is way easier because you can get rid of that nasty regex ;)

```
    String[] lines = new String[]{"Shortest path(2)::RV3280-RV0973C-RV2888C", "Shortest path(1)::RV3280-RV2502C", "Shortest path(2)::RV3280-RV2501C-RV1263", "Shortest path(2)::RV2363-Rv3285-RV3280", "\n", "\n"};
    final int positionOfIndex = 14;
    final int startPositionOfProteins = 18;
    for (String line : lines) {
        if (!line.trim().isEmpty()) {
            System.out.print(line.charAt(positionOfIndex) + ": ");
            String[] proteins = line.substring(startPositionOfProteins).split("-");
            System.out.println(proteins[0] + " " + proteins[proteins.size() -1]);

        }
    }
```

Comment: 2 empty lines in the end gives "No match result" as the first empty line is checked for matches. Your code does get rid of the "nasty" regex but what I need is just the first and the last proteins, not the complete list. Thanks anyway fielding, maybe I can use this somewhere else.

Comment: sry didnt see that.. i changed a single line, should work now.