# Java Scanner not recognizing lines in file

Tags: java, file, java.util.scanner

So I am using the following to read in a text file:

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileNotFoundException;
import java.util.Scanner;

String f = "file.txt";
Scanner in = new Scanner(new File(f));
while(in.hasNextLine()){
    //code here to make a matrix from the data in the text file
}
```

now this text file should create a matrix with 48927 rows (the number of lines in the text file). At the 196th row, the while loop breaks.

It used to be the 198th row, then I stripped white space (not the ending line break) and it moved to 196

I looked at both of these rows, and there is nothing differing them from the others!

**Why is scanner not reading them as lines?**

## rows

just to give you some inside on the file, here are what the rows look like (195-200):

```
CRUMBS BAKE SHOP<split>420<split>LEXINGTON AVENUE<split>10017<split>2122970500<split>2010-12-30 00:00:00<split>10.0<split>N<split>MANHATTAN<split>BAKERY

FAITHY'S KITCHEN<split>3907<split>DYRE AVENUE<split>10466<split>7186550780<split>2010-12-03 00:00:00<split>22.0<split>N<split>THE BRONX<split>CARIBBEAN

SIRUYEON<split>150-36<split>NORTHERN BOULEVARD<split>11354<split>7184616677<split>2013-05-07 00:00:00<split>60.0<split>N<split>QUEENS<split>CAFE, COFFEE, TEA

MILON BANGLASESH & INDIAN RESTAURANT<split>93<split>1 AVENUE<split>10003<split>2122284896<split>2013-02-20 00:00:00<split>19.0<split>B<split>BROOKLYN<split>BANGLADESHI

HOLEY CREAM<split>796<split>9 AVENUE<split>10019<split>2122478400<split>2011-07-18 00:00:00<split>16.0<split>B<split>MANHATTAN<split>ICE CREAM, GELATO, YOGURT, ICES

CHOP'T<split>1460<split>BROADWAY<split>10036<split>6465710601<split>2011-10-25 00:00:00<split>nan<split>A<split>MANHATTAN<split>SALADS
```

note: the commas in the last row is a common feature throughout the entire text file

## error

if I let the while loop go until an error, at line 196 (the line it cannot recognize) I get this error:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.NoSuchElementException: No line found
    at java.util.Scanner.nextLine(Scanner.java:1516)
```

Comment: Do you have any breaks in the omitted code or your code does not read any further?

Comment: do you have any error? or just stop reading?!

Comment: the reason the loop stops is not because of an error nor because of my code, it is because `in.hasNextLine()` becomes `false` AKA the scanner believes there is not another line yet there are 48700 more lines...

Comment: @X-Pippes I just added an error that I would get if I did not have the loop stop when it does not recognize the last line, but that does not really add anything to my knowledge because we already knew why the loop was stopping

Comment: Have you tried `in.hasNext()`?

Comment: @allejo it is looking for the next line though because the lines are specific to the rows for my matrix...but for the record that also breaks at the same line in the file

Comment: By any chance, in your omitted code do you have a condition where the scanner is closed?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you really have to use `Scanner`? 
Try to use `BufferedReader` with a `FileReader` instead.

check this

https://forums.oracle.com/message/4631933

[EDIT]

check this similar question 
[Problem using the nextLine() and hasNextLine() methods of Scanner](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3652586/problem-using-the-nextline-and-hasnextline-methods-of-scanner)

Comment: try to use the other to check if the problem is with file or with method

Comment: it fixed it although I don't understand why